# Python. Open file online

Tags: python, сервер

Всем привет, я хочу сделать так, чтобы скрипт просматривал переменные в онлайн-файле, возможно создать систему входа в аккаунт, с определенными правами доступа, но это не важно, нужно посмотреть python онлайн-файл, сверял данные, а так же мог включать строки в него. вот код онлайн файла онлайн:

```
user1 = ['0000000001', 'True', 'qwerty123']
```

этот файл будет хранить данные о пользователях на гугл диске вот код онлайн файла main.py:

```
#Первые строки должны читать содержимое онлайн файла
id = user1(1)
root_dostup = user1(2)
password = user1(3)
idcheck = input('Введите айди чтобы войти в аккаунт')
passcheck = input('Введите пароль')
#a дальше просто проверка аккаунта и данных на введение, писать это не нужно
```

Comment: Не понятно чем "онлайн" файл, отличается от просто файла. https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/fajly-rabota-s-fajlami.html  Посмотрите так же про форматы хранения. Если нужен читабельный текст - используйте json, если не обязательно, то можно использовать pickle

Comment: онлайн файл можно обновить, и он обновится у всех пользователей, однако если обновить офлайн файл, то его прийдётся обновлять пользователям самостоятельно, тем более что в данном файле будут хранится данные входа, в двоичном коде

Comment: И, да @Mike с онлайн файлом такого провернуть не получится, я уже пробовал

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: http://datalytics.ru/all/rabotaem-s-api-google-drive-s-pomoschyu-python/

Comment: А вообще вы лучше опишите для чего это вообще понадобилось, мне кажется у вас типичная проблема молотка https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-xy  Что то мне подсказывает, что вам нужна база данных или MQ (которые есть в том числе и онлайн и бесплатные в том числе)

Comment: @Mike мне это нужно для входжа в консоль, в которой будут права доступа

Comment: Ничего не понятно. зачем для входа куда то использовать файл на гугл диске. почему бы не положить такой файл на самом сервере